# Synonymize [vue-bootstrap] with [bootstrap-vue]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I just became aware today that there's a [vue-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-bootstrap) tag in addition to the more popular [bootstrap-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-vue) one.

The [library itself](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) is named BootstrapVue. The [bootstrap-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-vue) tag is by far the more popular of the two, with nearly 1000 questions, opposed to just 59 in the other. The more popular tag also has a wiki, while the other does not.

Can we synonymize the two, so that [vue-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-bootstrap) points to [bootstrap-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-vue)?

Comment: And more often than not, the two tags are actually used together in the same question. Have you suggested a synonym?

Comment: Looks fairly straightforward on this one. Synonymed. Can merge if there's no objections raised